# Return only certain filename without extension

Tags: python, os.walk

So from a previous post which I asked I found the following code to work:

```
b = os.walk('C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\FOLDER')
f = [] 
for(dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in b:
    f.extend(os.path.splitext(name)[0] for name in filenames)
    break
```

However, now I would like this list to return only a certain type of file, such as only the files that are .JPEG or .GIF (still without extension).

I already tried to use fnmatch, but it didn't work..

After comments I changed the code to:

```
b = os.walk('C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\FOLDER')
os.listdir('C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\FOLDER')
f = []
for(dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in b:
    f.extend(os.path.splitext(name)[0] for name in filenames if name.lower().endswith((".jpeg", ".gif")))

def save_to_file(text):
    for name in f:
        with open('C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\FOLDER\\test.txt', mode='wt', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
            myfile.write('\n'.join(text))
            myfile.write('\n')

save_to_file(f)
```

Comment: put if statement in that generator expression?

Comment: Have you tried reading the Python docs for the `os` module and basic built-in types + their methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *str.endswith* passing a tuple of extensions:

```
f.extend((os.path.splitext(name)[0] for name in filenames if name.lower().endswith((".jpeg", ".gif")))
```

I am not sure why you have a *break* in your for loop as that will mean you loop over one directory which you could be doing with `os.listdir`

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_files_by_filter(folder_path, filter):

    """
    :rtype : list
    """
    if not isdir(folder_path):
        log('Folder path: '+ str(folder_path) + ' not found')
        return []

    re_filter = re.compile(filter)
    all_files = listdir(folder_path)
    result = [file for file in all_files if re_filter.search(file)]
    return result
```

next:

```
file_name = []
for res in result:
    file_name.append(res.split('.')[0]
print(file_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to check each file name and return only a specific file type without the extension?
Since you're working on *Windows*, I guess you could do:

```
for filename in files:
    try:
        ext = filename.split('.')
        if ext[1].lower() == 'gif' or ext[1].lower() == 'jpeg':
            print ext[0]
    except IndexError:
        continue
```

Comment: This will throw an `IndexError` for any file without an extension

Comment: You are right. I didn't give a full-scope solution, only an idea. Anyway, I've updated the comment. Thank you.

Comment: that doesn't fix it at all. The try needs to be around the part where you access `ext[1]`

Comment: Meant continue. sorry.

Comment: You should really test your code before you run it, this still will give an `IndexError`. `filename.split(".")` won't cause an error even if the text doesn't have a ".". The part that causes the error is when you try to access the second element, `ext[1]`. There is no second element so this will cause the IndexError

Comment: And therefor the change. Thanks.